# I initialize local variable, but I still get "variable might not have been initialized"

Tags: java, variables

In:

```java
int i = 10;
int j;
    
if(i == 10) {
    j = 100;
}

System.out.println(j);//error
```

I get an error:

```
variable might not have been initialized
```

The compiler is not smart enough to determine the value of `j` even though in the above line it's been explicitly defined, as `int i = 10;`.

I think, `i` is not given value during compile time, and that's why I get this initialization error.

Does `int i` get `10` as its value during run-time?

Comment: Why have the `if` statement if you know `i` is going to be `10`?

Comment: Change `int i=10` to `final int i = 10`, and you'll know.

Comment: @Rohit that i know since it will be a compile time constant and compiler knows its values,thats what i am asking just because i have not declared it final does it mean it is given value at run time and that why compiler is not sure whether the if condition will be true for sure or not at compile time which results in error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `i` is local variable, `int i=10` is executed at runtime, so at compile time, compiler doesn't know that's value of `i`, so that the compiler cannot determine `if (i==10)` must be true, it can only assume the both condition. If `i` doesn't equal to 10, then `println` will use uninitialized `j`, that's reason why you get the error.

Comment: @Thanks Evan i was also thinking the same thats why i explicitly asked whether i is given value at run time

Answer (score 1):

You have to initialize j before executing the if-statement. All local variables must be defined and initialized.

In your program, because the compiler does not recognize the value of i, i == 10 is meaningless and gives an error.

Answer (score -1):

Try to remove the curly braces in your if statement.

Comment: What do you hope to accomplish by doing that?

Comment: nothing i just want to know at what time i is given value i think its not given at compile time and thats why compiler is not able to evaluate whether if statement would be true or not